# Passing Data from a JSP to Session Object

Tags: ajax, jsp, aem

I have a data of Product name and desc and its price in one JSP. And I want to pass it to a Servlet Session using Ajax Call. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

jsp is at server side and ajax call calling is from client side.
You need to store your data of Product name and desc and its price in some element to access it while calling.

```
<p id="yourDataID"> <%= yourData %> </p>
```

if you dont want display that data just use `display:none` style.

you can access that data for ajax calling like [Suvarna](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39266616/3526327) answered :

```
function function_name(){

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            //do what yoy want to do with xhttp response from servlet   
            }
      };
      xhttp.open("POST", "servlet_url", true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form urlencoded");
      xhttp.send("yourData=" + document.getElementById("yourDataID"));
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function function_name(){

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            //do what yoy want to do with xhttp response from servlet   
            }
      };
      xhttp.open("POST", "servlet_url", true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form urlencoded");
      xhttp.send('Productname=product1&desc=xyz&price=1000');
};
```